# Vagrant: concourse/lite version 2.2.1 cannot connect to ssh

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, concourse

I am running Virtualbox version 4.3.40r110317 with Vagrant 1.8.4 and am trying to start a concourse vm with vagrant.  I am trying to start a concourse/lite version 2.2.1 vagrant box, however any `vagrant up` will stall out at this point:

```
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
```

I am able to create a working concourse/lite version 1.2.0, but the later variations of version 2 that I have attempted to use all stall out at the same point.

For reference heres my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  # https://atlas.hashicorp.com/concourse/boxes/lite
  config.vm.box = "concourse/lite"
  config.vm.box_version = "2.2.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080

end
```

**Note:**

Due to some other dependency issues I cannot update my version of virtualbox.  If you happen to know the latest version of concourse that will work with my current version, it would help.

Comment: if you can downgrade your vagrant version , 1.7.2 or 1.7.3 would work well with virtualbox 4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So @AlexSuraci found it. The answer was: [manually clicking the "cable connected" checkbox on eth0 for the box.](https://github.com/concourse/concourse-lite/issues/9)

For reference to get to the `cable connected` checkbox do the following:

1. open virtualbox
2. right click the concourse VM
3. click settings
4. click network at the top of the popup window
5. select `Adapter 1`
6. at the bottom below `MAC address` and above `port forwarding` is the
   cable connected checkbox

Thanks [@zgagnon](https://github.com/zgagnon).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're running VirtualBox 5.1.x. Something changed backwards-incompatibly in VirtualBox that made boxes build with 5.1.x (as we do now for the Concourse boxes) have broken networking when run with 5.0.x.

Comment: Unfortunately due to some other dependancies I have I cannot change my version of Virtualbox.  Do you know whats the latest version of concourse/lite that will run on my current version?

Comment: There's a [workaround here](https://github.com/concourse/concourse-lite/issues/9) that should help.